# JavaScript replace figurative string line break with literal string line break

Tags: javascript

I have the following JavaScript variable:

```
var a = 'No line breaks\nhere!';
```

When I `console.log(a)` I recieve the following:

> No line breaks\nhere!

How do I replace a figurative string line break with a literal string line break?

I have tried the more obvious approaches:

```
a = a.replace('\n','\n');
```

Comment: When I `console.log(a)` I receive the text over two lines. Are you looking to escape it as `\\n`?

Comment: @ObsidianAge Obviously OP tried to reproduce the string he got from somewhere else and failed to notice that the "figurative line break" is `"\\n"` not `"\n"`.

Comment: How did you get that string might I ask?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Output from PHP. I'm trying to get line breaks working in Google Calendar API for the description field. Also I *just* had a two hour long conversation so I'm not ignoring you, just got back from lunch too. This seems to be working. This is the week of closing lots of tabs! :D

Comment: Then maybe the string is `JSON.stringify`-ed. Does it look something like: `'"No line breaks\nhere!"'`? (notice the double quotes `"`). In this case `JSON.parse` will do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "figurative line break" is actually two characters: the literal backslash `\` followed by the character `n`. To replace them you'll have to escape `\` to make it the literal `\` not the escape character itself:

```
a = a.replace('\\n', '\n');
```

**Note:** If you have more of those "figurative line breaks" then use a regex in the same way:

```
a = a.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
```

**Remember** That `"\\n".length === 2` (`'\'` followed by `'n'`) whereas `"\n".length === 1` (the line break character).